# When converting kivy file (.py) to apk, widgets are not automatically adjusting to device's window size

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I am trying to develop an andriod app using Kivy. I have used floatLayout to place the widgets. The output, when I run it on my linux is:

[Output in linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXRcr.png)

Then after converting it to apk, the widgets are getting compresed and texts flow out of widget and looking shabby :

[output on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stIyR.jpg)

my code :
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iZJq.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLNDU.png)

how can I make the widgets get adjusted automatically to the size of device(in my case Andriod). So that the texts doesnt flow outside the buttons and looks systamatic as it is in linux.

Comment: Rather than posting pictures of code, please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to check your kivy app in correct resolutions.So run in cmd : **python main.py --size=1440x2960** (phone device screensize opt.You can scale input sizes for your computer screen. Divide by 2/3/4/5..) So you can reedit your code after check in correct resolution.

Also you need to use metrics for your font sizes.Example: **font_size: '20sp'** . Use sp metrics for scale your fonts for all devices automaticly. [Check here for Kivy Metrics Docu.](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html)